# SuperScalar Out of Order Scheduling

Tags: cpu

[image]

In the figure above, isn't it SUB BX,4 be busy (in out of order scheduling)?? Why is that not busy? Because by the definition of out of order execution, we are just changing the way we schedule instructions. Instead of doing them sequentially, we do them in any order as long as there are no dependencies. Can anyone give the logic behind filling table 15.4? I can follow table 15.3 but not table 15.4

Answer (score 0):

In the out-of-order processor, SUB BX,4 isn't data dependent on the results of another instruction. So it can begin execution because a pipeline, #2, is available although that pipeline is also busy with the load. It's a *pipeline* with multiple instructions in flight rather than simply a two cycle functional unit with only one instruction. MOV CX,2000 also issues because it is available.

Now there is a bubble because the load isn't finished and another instruction can't be found to execute. So it's marked busy for a cycle. Now the result of the load is available in DL and the next instruction can execute in pipeline 1 in cycle 4. Pipeline #2 goes idle because, I assume, the SUB took two cycles.

You don't give enough information about instruction latencies.